# How to update a zset score with "where clause" in redis

Tags: sql, database, redis

In MySQL :

```
update zset.1 set score = score + 10 where value = 1 and score > 100
```

It means it won't update except the score is gt 100

In Redis and program code:

```
score = zscore zset.1 1
if (score > 100) {
  score = zincrby zset.1 10 1
}
```

This should work but it's not atomic. The score will be updated several times when updating concurrently

Also, "WATCH" is not appropriate for my situation since its RETRY mechanism will be a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing it:

- Use Redis `multi()`/`exec()` combination to execute a series of Redis calls atomically. [See Redis Transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions).
- Write a Lua script. See [documentation for `eval` function in Redis](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL)  for more information.